# duplicate title tags and descriptions in webmaster tools

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, google-search-console

Still a bit new at this so please go easy on me and I have tried searching for an answer but have been unable to find one that specifically helps me. I have a wordpress site that I have built a custom php page to deliver results from a database to display information and have manually inserted code to display the header and footer of my wordpress theme.

Also, in my `.htaccess` I have used the

```
rewriterule ^used-boats-for-sale/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /boatdetails.php?recordnumber=$5 [L]
```

to forward the friendly url so the php page can process the correct record number to process and display the results. This was the only way I could figure out how to do this in `wordpress` and bypass wordpress's subfolder killer.

My issue arises as google webmaster tools is telling me I have duplicate title tags and descriptions, even though I have added a canonical reference to the friendly url.

Examples of both can be seen here:

> ```
> http://www.unitedyacht.com/used-boats-for-sale/hinckley/downeast/cruiser/2000/1807/
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> http://www.unitedyacht.com/boatdetails.php?recordnumber=1807
> ```

So with the canonical, why is google still showing it as a dupe and what can I do to correct it? If I put a `r=301` in, it redirects the url completely and removes the friendly url from the browser.

Comment: Do you face the same problem after requesting Google for a new crawl?

Comment: Alright, and I believe the fact that when the friendly URL is typed in _without www_ redirects to the one with parameter passing, is a bad approach. It should either be both (with or without www) redirected to the second URL, or neither of them. Any approach you could avoid doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you show me an example of what you mean please?

Comment: Well right now, there is an obvious problem and that is when you enter the **first URL** (without www):

http://unitedyacht.com/used-boats-for-sale/hinckley/downeast/cruiser/2000/1807/

You will get redirected to the **second URL** which is: 

http://www.unitedyacht.com/boatdetails.php?recordnumber=1807

Why is this approach being used? Any way to avoid doing this?